# SoaupUI - Groovy replace All

Tags: regex, groovy, replace, soapui

I have a string which contains some xml tags with namespaces and I'm trying to remove the namespaces from the closing tag. I have tried using the method below

```
staticData = staticData.replaceAll('/Group xmlns="http://socialservices.gov.au/ebo/QualityIndicators"','/Group>')
```

It isn't finding the text in the string. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression it's only to remove specific namespace from specific tag (besides you're adding and extra `>` to group).

You can try to be more generic using `replaceAll` with the follow regular expression to remove namespaces from any closed tag.

```
   def staticData = 
'''<root>
<Group>
</Group xmlns="http://a">
<Group>
</Group xmlns="http://b">
<Group>
</Group xmlns="http://socialservices.gov.au/ebo/QualityIndicators">
<Different>
</Different xmlns="http://socialservices.gov.au/ebo/QualityIndicators">
<Normal>
</Normal>
</root>'''

staticData = staticData.replaceAll(/\<\/(\w*)\s[\S-\>]*\>/){ match, capture ->
    return "</$capture>"
}

println staticData
```

This script returns:

```
<root>
<Group>
</Group>
<Group>
</Group>
<Group>
</Group>
<Different>
</Different>
<Normal>
</Normal>
</root>
```

Regex explanation `/\<\/(\w*)\s[\S-\>]*\>/` :

It matches the text that starts with `</` (`\<\/`) followed by 0 or n characters capturing this group (`(\w*)`), then followed with one space (`\s`) and then any character except space and `>` 0 or n times (`[\S-\>]*`) and finally `>` char (`\>`).

Hope it helps,